# Lucene index mapping with xml structure

Tags: xml, lucene

I am new in lucene. I just want to implement the lucene search in my application but when i trying to do indexing in following xml file, i am getting wrong set of results, as in my application there are several xml files are present such as

```
<Category s="Mammals">
  <sub P="Dolphin"/>
  <sub P="Bat"/>
  <sub P="Wales"/>  
  <sub P="Human"/>
  <sub P="Dog"/>
  <sub P="Cat"/>
</Category>

<Category s="Birds">
  <sub P="Spparrow"/>
  <sub P="Crow"/>
  <sub P="Pengvins"/>
  <sub P="Peacock"/>
</Category>
```

When i finished the indexing on above xml code and start testing by searching i am getting wrong result like when i trying search for category  "Mammals" and sub category "Crow" i am getting result like category "Mammals" and sub category "Crow" but i do not want such result, in this case i just want result like category "Mammals" do not contain sub category "Crow". In short i just want apply condition
So how do i make lucene index with map with database structure for getting correct structure

Comment: I am also facing such kind of problem.

Comment: How do you perform the indexing? Please post that code. How do you search? Please post that code also.